# Creating a for loop or function to create multiple heatmaps from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop, seaborn

I'm relatively new to python, so I'm not that great with for/while loops or functions.

Basically, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
temp | dewpoint | wind | precip_rate_hr | total_snow
-------------------------------------------------
31        20       3         0.2            2.1
29        25       12         0.01           0.7
30        30       17         0.5            4.1
...      ...      ...         ...            ...
```

I've been creating heatmaps using seaborne that compare the first four columns, with total_snow mean between the two variables being shown. Apologies if that doesn't sound right. Here's my code:

```
snow_data_percentile_10_temp = np.percentile(snow_data['temp'], 10)
snow_data_percentile_50_temp = np.percentile(snow_data['temp'], 50)
snow_data_percentile_75_temp = np.percentile(snow_data['temp'], 75)

snow_data_percentile_10_dewpt = np.percentile(snow_data['dewpoint'], 10)
snow_data_percentile_50_dewpt = np.percentile(snow_data['dewpoint'], 50)
snow_data_percentile_75_dewpt = np.percentile(snow_data['dewpoint'], 75)

snow_data['temp_bin'] = pd.cut(snow_data['temp'], [0, 10.4, 23.5, 28.75, 37], labels=['<10.4', '10.4-23.5', '23.5-28.75', '>28.75'])
snow_data['dewpt_bin'] = pd.cut(snow_data['dewpoint'], [0, 4.1, 15, 19.75, 33], labels=['<4.1', '4.1-15', '15-19.75', '>19.75'])

avg_snow = snow_data.groupby(['temp_bin','dewpt_bin'], as_index=False)['total_snow'].mean()

data_fp = avg_snow.pivot_table(index='temp_bin', columns='dewpt_bin', values='total_snow')
sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,25))
sns.set(font_scale=2.0)
sns.heatmap(data_fp, annot=True, fmt='g', linewidth=0.5) 
ax.set_title('Average Snow Total on Days that Met Specific Temperature and Dewpoint Criteria', fontsize=20)
```

Here's a capture of the heatmap. The values displayed on the bins are the average snow totals for those bins. Is there a way to streamline this code? I need to create heatmaps for temp vs wind, temp vs precip_rate_hr, dewpoint vs wind, dewpoint vs precip_rate_hr, wind vs precip_rate_hr. I also have another, larger dataset I'll need to work through. Right now, I'm just copying and pasting the code into new files and changing it around some to get the rest of the heatmaps. That doesn't take too long, but I would like to automate it more and prevent myself from having numerous code files. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Heatmap created]

Comment: Where are you using the `np.percentile` lines? You assign them but never use them. With hard-coded `pd.cut` bins, you could not automate across other paired types unless you have them saved separately.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Forgot about that. I ended up changing it to have them included; before, with this code, I was just manually inputting the values after running the np.percentile lines. I before didn't have them put into the code anywhere else, I just used the values that were found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to create all the charts in a loop.  It isn't the cleanest, as there will be repeated charts (but with the axes swapped).

My data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

snow_data = pd.DataFrame(data={"temp": np.random.randint(20, 40, 50), "dewpoint": np.random.randint(15, 40, 50),
                               "wind": np.random.randint(0, 20, 50), "precip_rate_hr": np.random.random(50),
                               "total_snow": np.random.random(50)*10})
```

Creating the categories (this is not in a loop as the bins are all different):

```
snow_data['temp_bin'] = pd.cut(snow_data['temp'], [0, 10.4, 23.5, 28.75, 37], labels=['<10.4', '10.4-23.5', '23.5-28.75', '>28.75'])
snow_data['dewpt_bin'] = pd.cut(snow_data['dewpoint'], [0, 4.1, 15, 19.75, 33], labels=['<4.1', '4.1-15', '15-19.75', '>19.75'])
snow_data['wind_bin'] = pd.cut(snow_data['wind'], [0, 5, 10, 15, 20], labels=['<5', '5-10', '10-15', '15-20'])
snow_data['precip_rate_hr_bin'] = pd.cut(snow_data['precip_rate_hr'], [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], labels=['<0.25', '0.25-0.5', '0.5-0.75', '>0.75'])
```

The loop:

```
# List of all _bin columns to loop through
bin_cols = ['temp_bin', 'dewpt_bin', 'wind_bin', 'precip_rate_hr_bin']

# First factor
for i in bin_cols:
    # Second factor
    for j in bin_cols:
        # Need to ensure you aren't grouping the data by the same column twice!
        if j != i:
            # Average now mean for bin groups
            avg_snow = snow_data.groupby([i, j], as_index=False)['total_snow'].mean()
            # Title for plot
            title = 'Average Snow Total on Days that Met Specific ' + i[: -4] + ' and ' + j[: -4] + ' Criteria'
            # Pivot table
            data_fp = avg_snow.pivot_table(index=i, columns=j, values='total_snow')
            # Plot
            sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
            f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 25))
            sns.set(font_scale=2.0)
            sns.heatmap(data_fp, annot=True, fmt='g', linewidth=0.5)
            ax.set_title(title, fontsize=20)
            plt.show()
```

I agree with Parfait's comment about not needing the `np.percentile`, unless you are using these to find appropriate categories for the _bin columns.